# C++ global variable writable from multiple object instances

Tags: c++, global-variables

Can I make a global variable(of type array or vector, preferably) which can be written (new row every time, of course) by multiple object instances of same class?

Thank you.

(Note: If required I can give brief description of my project to give better idea.)

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time"? Is this a multi-threaded scenario?

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, I am actually implementing this in the SystemC (Derived from C++ for Hardware description), so I can say that this a multi-threaded situation. At compile time, n-number of "senders" and "receivers" objects are made. I need to write a global variable, which will be filled (new row for every data), with the copy of a sender's data and receiver's data. So that in the end I can compare a sent data list against received data list, to check if all data sent by all nodes is received by appropriate receiving node. I hope that clarifies a little. I am sorry about this ling description!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a `static` member. (or a regular global variable, but since it's apparently connected to a class, but not a particular instance, seems like a `static` member is the way to go)

```
class Foo
{
   static std::vector<int> vec;  //vec is common for all instances of Foo
};

//Foo.cpp
std::vector<int> Foo::vec;  //define it in the implementation file
```